# Coding a variable based on time trends in R?

Tags: r, time-series

So my question isn't about R code *per se*, it is more of a code structure or logic problem.  Say I have travel data from every night in 2017 for a group of people.  Every line in my data frame is the location where a person was during the night (by county).  So it looks something like this:

```
x <- data.frame("name" = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "Dora", "Dora", "Dora", "Dora"), 
"date" = c("1/1/19","1/2/19","1/3/19","1/4/19","1/1/19","1/2/19","1/3/19","1/4/19"),
"county" = c("county 1", "county 1", "county 2", "county 1", "county 1", "county 1", "county 2", "county 2"))
```

In reality the data is much more complex than this.  But this is the basic idea.  In this scenario John leaves his home county (county 1) to spend a night visiting county 2.  In contrast Dora leaves her home county 1 and moves to county 2 (she does not return to county 1 within the timeframe of the data).  How would I go about coding a variable that would tell me who is a traveler (e.g. John) and who is a mover (e.g. Dora)?  I want to label John at 'home' for all nights but his one county 2 night when I want him labeled 'traveler'.  I want Dora labeled 'home' for every county 1 night and 'moved' for every county 2 night.

Assume someone could travel for as many as 363 nights in a row to more than one county.

I'm not sure my data is in the right format to answer this question, but it is very large (too large to make wide).

Answer (score 0):

With the data as is, you wouldn't be able to. Take the following example

```
Dora 1/1/19 county 1
Dora 1/2/19 county 1
Dora 1/3/19 county 2
Dora 1/4/19 county 2
```

How would you know if Dora is now a permanent resident in county 2, or someone staying for a long vacation/hiatus. Another example

```
John 1/1/19 county 1
John 1/2/19 county 2
John 1/3/19 county 2
John 1/4/19 county 1
```

You wouldn't be able to tell if John was traveling to county 2 for 2 nights, or maybe he moved to county 2 and traveled back to county 1 for some reason.

Comment: I am aware that the operationalization of my variable is not perfect, and that there are constraints on the data that are unknowable.  That being said, I need to know how to produce the variable in question, even with its limitations.

Comment: You cannot. As illustrated in my examples, there's no way to tell if John or Dora are travelers or new residents based on what you've given. You'd either have to give more information to help pinpoint the difference between a traveler or new migrant, or make drastically simplifying assumptions about the individuals in your dataset (e.g. people who stay in another county for more than X days are residents).